# JDK not recognized after installation in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.10

I did these steps without error:

1. JDK path :

   ```
   Downloads/jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin
   ```
2. Commands in Terminal:

   ```
   mkdir Programs
   cd Programs
   bash ../Downloads/jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin
   ln -s jdk-6u37-linux-x64 jdk
   ```
3. Set JAVA_HOME and Path:

   I added the following lines to the end of the `.bashrc` file:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=$Home/Programs/jdk
   export PATH=:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

---

This is the result of executing the command `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/Programs/jdk
```

This is the result of executing the command `echo $PATH`:

```
:/Programs/jdk/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games1
```

---

And the problem is:
This is the result of executing the command

```
$ java -version

The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install
```

Comment: just re-install  it , might have missed some file , it should  work  for you :)

Comment: The easiest way would be to get an official ubuntu package, on my side I'm using Slackware but to get custom JDK package I use official compilation scripts... Ubuntu have already up to date packages so why not just use them?

Comment: What does `which java` tell you?

Comment: Oh, and lose the first `:` in `export PATH=:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that environment variables are case sensitive in linux, so your

```
export JAVA_HOME=$Home/Programs/jdk
```

Should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Programs/jdk
```

In your `echo $JAVA_HOME` output you can see that you don't get your `/home/yourname` prepended...

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. ‌But Why is this form ? My home folder is exactly Home, not HOME.

Comment: $HOME is the environment variable _representing_ your home directory, not the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

The scripts located [here](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) will help you install sun's jdk on Ubuntu. Really useful stuff.

Comment: Is this just a software repository for easier Download and access  to the JDK? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The scripts download the jdk from Sun, then they do some apt magic to package them for apt, then you just run an apt upgrade (or update?) and it will set them up for you. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will list all the Java versions installed and configured.

If you see one or more installs, it will give you a list each element starting with a number. Just choose the number that corresponds to the version you want to use by default.